# Print /n On xCode Playground

Tags: ios, swift

When I am writing code in an Xcode Playground, the Play Ground Print "/n" On latest of my code result. How can I fix it?

[image: Image Of My Question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In swift 2, there has no `println` anymore.

`Print` is now equivalent to `println` before, so it has "\n".

The way to fix it:

```
print(saeed, terminator: "")
```

Comment: Read what khuong said. If you add `terminator: ""` as a second parameter, it does not add a newline at the end of the line.